# Available networks disappear after a while?

Tags: networking, lubuntu

So basically, when I boot up my laptop and look at the available networks, I can see, well, the available networks that are near me. But after a while (say about 1-3 minutes) they disappear. I'm still connected to the current internet connection but I can't see the other ones.

How do I fix this so I can see the other networks that I'm not connected to without having to restart the laptop everytime?

What I've tried so far is changing

```
wifi.powersave = 3
```

in the `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`
to

`wifi.powersave = 2`

I'm using Lubuntu 21.10 on a Lenovo ThinkPad E14 Gen 3

Comment: I am facing same problem. I have asus tuf ubuntu 22.04. Did you solve the problem?